# How to draw only the visible pixels which are >0% alpha with a custom color in canvas?

Tags: algorithm, canvas, hit

I would like to make a good performance hit test for png images and other shapes. I don't really care what shapes they are because with this technique there is no performance issues at checking (not setup).

I intent to collect all the images on the screen in a secondary canvas just for hit test. For each image drawn I will create a new color which is attached to that particular image. Then I draw all of them in the canvas, each image will have a different fill color.

When I click on a pixel (x, y) it will get the color (r, g, b). Every color is mapped to a image, so I get the image clicked with no error (I don't waste with finding what was hit with that click).

[image]

I know it will be limited to 256*256*256=16 777 216 items because those are all the colors but I don't think it will be a problem for now...

So what I really need is to know how to put those fill colors on the secondary canvas which is based only on the visible pixels for each image.

**UPDATE**

[image]
As you can see to the right it's the hit test map. So if I click on the black shade (c) I instantly know I've clicked on the blue box without any other calculation.

One improvement it would be to cache the alpha data. Also reuse the same alpha data for each image instance (we must take care about scaling and rotation...).

thanks

Comment: What's wrong with other collision detection tests?

Comment: The collision detection doesn't check in each image each pixel if was hitten or not? that would be too slow for about a >1000 tiles each about 1000 pixel. (1000000 checks for each mouseover would be very laggy). I don't even know if my idea works, as it occurred to me just 15 minutes ago...

Comment: http://active.tutsplus.com/sessions/collision-detection-and-reaction/

Comment: well, that seems to be made for flash. What I needed is a way to draw the fill areas of the images in canvas for html+javascript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here’s how you would color-mask the non-transparent pixels of a canvas image.

Be sure you replace "PutYourImageHere.png" with your own image url.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>

<style>
    body{ background-color: ivory; }
    canvas{border:1px solid blue;}
</style>

<script>
    $(function(){

        var img=new Image();
        img.onload=function(){

          var red=255;
          var blue=0;
          var green=0;

          var canvasCopy=document.getElementById("canvasCopy");
          var ctxCopy=canvasCopy.getContext("2d");

          var c=document.getElementById("canvas");
          var ctx=c.getContext("2d");
          ctx.drawImage(this,0,0);

          var imgData=ctx.getImageData(0,0,c.width,c.height);

          for (var i=0;i<imgData.data.length;i+=4)
            {
                if(imgData.data[i+3]>0){
                    imgData.data[i]=red;
                    imgData.data[i+1]=green;
                    imgData.data[i+2]=blue;
                    imgData.data[i+3]=255;
                }
            }
          ctxCopy.putImageData(imgData,0,0);
        }
        img.src = "PutYourImageHere.png";

    }); // end $(function(){});
</script>

</head>

<body>

    <canvas id="canvas" width="300" height="300"></canvas>
    <canvas id="canvasCopy" width="300" height="300"></canvas>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I think it will work! I'm not able to test it right now, but it seems to be exactly what I wanted. I didn't know that the imageData was structured this way [pixels1.red, pixel1.green, pixel1.blue, pixel2.alpha, pixel2.red].. Do you know any link that explain this topic more deeply? thanks (:

Comment: Well just dirty tested right now and it works perfectly! Thanks very very much! http://jsfiddle.net/Tj5qG/1/

Comment: Glad I could help.  Some optimization tips: ---  1. Cache imgData.data as var data=imgData.data, --- 2. You can grab a smaller portion of the canvas instead of the whole thing: var myArea=ctx.getImageData(X,Y,Width,Height), --- 3. Best optimization possible: Calc the bounding boxes(BB) of your images and test the BB’s for collision so if there’s no collision you can avoid the collision testing ENTIRELY!

Comment: Well, I think you didn't understand well my idea. I will just post an image in my question explaining exactly how it will work..